# Next JS error while using JSX tags

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import factory from '../ethereum/factory';


class CampaignIndex extends Component {

    static async getInitialProps(){
        const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();

        return { campaigns };
    }

    renderCampaigns() {
        const items = this.props.campaigns.map(address =>{
            return {
                header: address,
                description: 'View campaign',
                fluid: true
            };
        });

        return( 
            <Card.Group items={items}/>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.rendercampaigns() 
        )
    } 
}

export default CampaignIndex;
```

```
  Syntax Error: Unexpected token (26:12)    
  24 |
  25 |         return(
> 26 |             <Card.Group items={items}/>
     |             ^
  27 |         );
  28 |     }
  29 |
```

I get the similar error whenever I try to use any of the '<>' tags in my program.

I am using next js with sematic-ui-react.

To run it I use `npm run dev` on localhost:3000.

Can anyone help me out with anything.

Comment: is this a jsx file? This won't be a proble of your code but of the way you are transpiling it. The JSX syntax is obviously not recognized.

Comment: It is index.js file for my next js project.